# Add WiFi 6 Mesh to existing WiFi without ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

Are there WiFi 6 "Mesh" devices which can link to my existing WiFi router?

Another way of saying this is, are there devices that support a wireless / WiFi "backhaul" rather than wired? I've checked out various manufacturers and none of their documentation is clear, either.

I keep seeing people asking this question on various sites and no one giving them a straight answer. Here is why I (and I assume others) have asked this:

1. For some of us, wired is NOT an option. There are many ISPs who offer WiFi only routers now, without ANY ethernet connection, so we simply can't. Some may just not want to run ethernet cable all over their house - but in my specific case, I have a router with no ethernet on it.
2. We understand that there will be a drop in speed with each "hop". Speed is not what is important here, it's having ANY CONNECTION AT ALL. I can get over 100 mbps right at my router, but there are parts of my house where I have no connection, or the connection repeatedly drops out completely. If the farthest corner of my house only gets 10 mbps, then so be it...
3. WiFi Extenders are kludgy and devices have to disconnect / reconnect if you move around the house. We would like the smooth transition of a WiFi 6 "Mesh" network...

Comment: In order to use those “mesh network kits” a base unit must be connected directly to the modem or an appropriate network switch (which itself is connected to the modem).

Comment: FYI: I found a "happy medium" of a WiFi 6 "Mesh Extender". Specific model Netgear AX1800. It's not technically a "Mesh" it's just one device and doesn't have all the features of other "Mesh" kits. Just acting as a repeater/extender for my Starlink WiFi (WiFi 5). 30% Cheaper than the Starlink Mesh device and no wait either. Readily available at a store near me. I don't know if hand offs will be an issue, but so far I haven't noticed any and I now have a strong WiFi signal throughout my house. I also split the Starlink WiFi into separate 2.4 / 5 GHz networks, so I can assign based on distance.

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge is mostly for TP-Link devices.

TP-Link have limited list of edge routers/repeater/range extenders which support or can be upgraded with firmware for TP-Link Mesh protocol. If you are lucky just add some additional Mesh devices and extend the coverage. If not you will need to replace your router with compatible device or with one Mesh unit and build the network.

As you do not want to add cables have you consider to extend your network via Ethernet over powerlines? They support up to 1Gbit speed and up to 300 meters distance.

Based on your clarifications my best idea is to use second router for bridge (to give you 4 ethernet ports) and few ethernet over power line. Those over power line have WiFi and/or ethernet port. Yes, you loose the roaming option but you will get stable and relatively fast connection.

I have apoint to mention: **+** you may not need router because some TP_Link power line adapters can act as bridge.

Comment: I guess part of my issue is, for all the mesh products I've looked at, downloaded the manuals, and read them, they all talk about connecting an Ethernet cable to the WAN port to install and set up, including TP-Link. None seem to have instructions on doing the wireless backhaul channel... so it makes me not confident that it will work. If I had one in hand, I could probably figure it out but I don't want to buy something just to have to return it because it can't do what I need...

Comment: @Trashman, you can create with edge router bridge between your ISP and first Mesh device. And you will have only short patch cable between your router and 1st Mesh unit

Comment: You don't understand... I cannot connect an ethernet cable to my ISP's router. It is wireless only, straight to their lines. There is no port, no where to connect ethernet to it whatsoever...

Comment: Can you replace the ISP router?

Comment: @Trashman - What the model of the modem that’s extremely odd

Comment: I tried not posting my life story... but now I have to give a longer explanation. I'm using Starlink, Gen 2 Generation 1 had Ethernet AND could be used with 3rd party equipment. However, they removed Ethernet from Gen 2 and there is also currently no 3rd party routers available or supported (the cable itself has a proprietary plug on it). Technically, it DOES have an Ethernet adapter available, and it's not expensive, only $25. The problem for me is, my office shutdown and I have to work from home so I need a solution NOW... 6-8 weeks to get the Adapter shipped. I can get a kit today.

Comment: Futher explanations / technicalities: I could rearrange my entire house to bring my home office closer to the router (I can only move the router over a few feet), but I don't really want to do that. I also could get a WiFi extender, which I guess gets me through the current situation while I wait for the Ethernet adapter to come... but if at all possible, I'd like to have the long term solution now and not have to waste my money on the extender I will be getting rid of in a couple months From an engineering perspective, a device that does this is completely possible, I guess no one makes one

Comment: Also, I'm aware that there's also a Starlink Mesh available - but they're WiFi 5 and cost $130 per unit - and again, will take 6-8 weeks to ship. There are decent (not the best, but still better than WiFi 5) WiFi 6 mesh kits with three units already included for around the same price.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Ethernet over power line is another possibility, I suppose. However, I'm concerned that will drop out whenever we're doing laundry...  Unless someone has figured out a way to do purely WiFi-to-WIFI Mesh, I'll probably opt to do a cheap extender in the short term and wait for the adapter in the long term...  then buy a mesh kit after I get the adapter.

Comment: @Trashman, my personal experience with old TP-Link over power line, 100 Mbits show quite reliable connection and I did not observer interruptions during laundry.

Comment: @Trashman, I added a bit more info in the answer.

Comment: The fact your using a Starlink terminal is pretty relevant

Comment: @Ramhound I never assume that the same situation DOESN'T apply to someone with a different product, so I try to ask my question as generically as possible. Also, I think if there is a good mesh extension option out there that some people might prefer it over these other alternatives, too. Some people ask bad questions, but I think a lot of people on StackExchange tend to jump into questioning the OP rather than just answering the question - even when it has an answer! Might not be the "best" solution, but doesn't mean it can't be done. The OP might have a good reason.

Comment: I already knew that Starlink terminals don’t have a Ethernet port, so knowing you were using one would have changed my original response.